# Flutter send intent like in Java Android

Tags: android, flutter

I would like open another app activity using intent (send from Flutter).

For example when try open another app activity using intent (send from Java Android) it looks next:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction("test.intent");
sendBroadcast(sendIntent);
```

How can I do the same on Flutter?

Comment: are you referring just passing data

Comment: not just, for example my second app have 4 activities, using intent I would like open 4th activity

Comment: ok you like open 4th activity page with passing data?

Comment: yes, passing data